# MVC4 section name with dot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on a project which has several sections defined as follows:

```
@RenderSection("Sidebar.Top", false)
<div>somecontent</div>
@RenderSection("Sidebar.Bottom", false)
```

I want to render something in the bottom sidebar section, but when I use `@section Sidebar.Bottom{}` I get an error message saying

> Cannot resolve section 'Sidebar'

Am I not allowed to use a `.` in a section name or is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You just can't use a dot.

Comment: It's those little problems which make SO such a valuable resource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can't use points in a section name, but it's a very good question!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a "." in the name of a section.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use "."s in section names in ASP.NET MVC 4.0